# How to show json data into html <ul><li></li></ul> tag using jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am working on asp.net application where i am trying to fetch data from database in JSON format and display that JSON data into html-ul-li tag using jquery. My Html Page is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //function GetCompanies() {
    $(document).ready(function () {

       $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MobileServices.asmx/BindCategory",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});

function OnSuccess(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value{
        $("#ulCategory").append("<li><a rel=external href=Category_News.html?ID=" + value.Category_ID + ">" + value.Category_Name + "</li>");
    })

}
function OnError(data) {

}
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ul id="ulCategory">

        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My WebService to Access the Data is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Configuration;
namespace MobileNewsAppication
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MobileServices
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]


    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class MobileServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        public class NewsCategory
        {
            public long Category_ID { get; set; }
            public string Category_Name { get; set; }
            public string QFlag { get; set; }
        }



        [WebMethod]
        public string BindAllCategory()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //List<NewsCategory> details = new List<NewsCategory>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AllCategory_Select", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

            }

        }
    }
    }
```

But the the ul Tag is not binding any list item inside. I think foreach loop defined inside jquery OnSuccess method may be wrong. Please help me.

Comment: exactly do you wanna iterate the JSON data right. is in it?

Comment: i want to display data in ul tag

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't a typo here then it's a syntax error causing the success callback to fail...

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
//  $.each(data, function (key, value{ <- this is wrong
    $.each(data, function() {
        $("#ulCategory").append("<li><a rel='external' href='Category_News.html?ID=" + this.Category_ID + "'>" + this.Category_Name + "</li>");
    });
}
```

Try using `this` inside `each` instead.  I also wrapped the link attributes in quotes.  Other than that it looks fine to me.  If that isn't the issue then put `console.log(data);` as the 1st line of the success callback and check the console for that and any errors.

Comment: I've modified the answer slightly.  Try that and let us know how you get on.

Comment: It is not getting right. Inside the ul tag it is showing "undefined" in place of "Category_Name" only single time but my data is returning 8 rows.

Comment: Did you try putting a `console.log` in there like I suggested?  Let me know the output

Comment: Object {d: "[{"Category_ID":1,"Category_Name":"मुख्य खबर"},{"C…बम "},{"Category_ID":12,"Category_Name":"विशेष"}]"}
d: "[{"Category_ID":1,"Category_Name":"मुख्य खबर"},{"Category_ID":2,"Category_Name":"देश  विदेश"},{"Category_ID":3,"Category_Name":"छत्तीसगढ"},{"Category_ID":5,"Category_Name":"सम्पादकीय"},{"Category_ID":6,"Category_Name":"पोल खाता"},{"Category_ID":7,"Category_Name":"ज्ञान  रंजन"},{"Category_ID":11,"Category_Name":"पत्रबम "},{"Category_ID":12,"Category_Name":"विशेष"}]"

Comment: That data doesn't make sense.  It's not a valid json string.  Try checking it yourself on http://jsonlint.com/ .  Until you're getting valid json, you can't do anything with it.

Comment: The returned data is valid json data. I have checked it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can tell you just by looking at what you posted that it is not valid.  There's not even a closing brace for starters, and there could be any number of things wrong with it after that.  There are incomplete objects, commas missing - it's totally not valid.  If you say that's valid JSON then I can help you no more.